# Why is my txt file not opening successfully? c++

Tags: c++, xcode, txt

I am trying to open the txt file I made for the rest of my code to successfully run. I am using c++ and xcode is the environment. When I run my code, I get this:

error in opening studentScore8.txt

And below that is the correct formatting for the table but weird numbers are there. I am confident that the location for the file is correct, and I am not seeing any issues in my code besides

```
printGrade(oneScore, average);
```

in the main function, which xcode is saying that the parameters oneScore and average are not initialized, but I thought I already did that above.

Does anyone know what the issue could be? This is a lab for my comp sci class, and my teacher doesn't seem to know what the issue is either. I am thinking it has something to do with xcode or my computer itself, but I am not sure. The entire code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define inFile "/Users/spacecowboy/Desktop/cis/cis/lab 8/studentScore8.txt"


const int MAX_SIZE = 4;
void readStuData (ifstream& rss, int scores[], int id[], int& count, bool& tooMany);
float mean(int scores[], int count);
void printTable(int scores[], int id[], int count);
void printGrade(int oneScore, float average);


int main() {
    ifstream rss;
   // void printTable(scores, id, count);
   // float mean(int scores, int count);
    float average;
    bool tooMany;
    int scores[MAX_SIZE];
    int oneScore;
    int id[MAX_SIZE];
    int count;
    
    rss.open("studentScore8.txt");
    
    if (rss.fail()){
        cout << "error in opening studentScore8.txt" << endl;
    }
    
    readStuData(rss, scores, id, count, tooMany);
    mean(scores, count);
    printGrade(oneScore, average);
    printTable(scores, id, count);
    
    rss.close();
    return 0;
    }

void readStuData(ifstream& rss, int scores[], int id[], int& count,bool& tooMany){
    int stuID;
    int stuScore;
    int i;
    
       for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i) {
          rss >> stuID;
          rss >> stuScore;
           id[i] = stuID;
           scores[i] = stuScore;
           ++count;
       }
    
    if (count > MAX_SIZE){
        tooMany = true;
    }
    else {
        tooMany = false;
    }
   
}

float mean(int scores[], int count)
{
float sum = 0;
int i;
        
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    sum = sum + scores[i];
}
    return sum / count;

}
    

void printGrade(int oneScore, float average){
    ifstream rss;
    
    rss >> oneScore;
    
    if (((oneScore >= average -10) && (oneScore <= average + 10))) {
            cout << "Satisfactory";
        }
            else if (oneScore == average + 10){
                cout << "Satisfactory";
            }
            else if (oneScore > average + 10){
                cout << "Outstanding";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Unsatisfactory";
            }
        
       }
    


void printTable(int scores[], int id[], int count){
    int i;
  
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Student ID" << "|";
    cout << setw(6) << right << "Score" << "|" ;
    cout << setw(14) << left << "Grade" << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(30) << "" << endl;
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i){
        cout << left << setw(10) << id[i] << "|";
        cout << left << " ";
        cout << setw(2) << scores[i];
        cout << right << " " << "|";
        printGrade(scores[i], mean(scores, count));
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout<< setfill('-') << setw(30) << "" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `rss.open("studentScore8.txt");` uses a relative path and sometimes the program is run from somewhere you don't expect, making it impossible to predict where the current [working dirfectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is. Looks like you're meant to use the explicit path in `inFile`.

Comment: Was `inFile` intended to be used anywhere in your program?

Comment: in void printGrade i don't see any open tbh

Comment: thank you @user4581301 your advice really really helped.